# USB Hub Error -62

Tags: linux, usb, embedded, hub

I have a 5m usb cable which I want to connect to a usb port on a embedded device (linux debarm; kernel 2.6). The cable has one repeater so it's actually two cables with one hub between. When I plug it in `dmesg` shows me:

```
usb 1-1: new full speed USB device using at91_ohci and address 23
hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
usb 1-1.4: new full speed USB device using at91_ohci and address 24
usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/all, error -62
usb 1-1.4: new full speed USB device using at91_ohci and address 25
hub 1-1.4:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-1.4:1.0: 4 ports detected
hub 1-1.4:1.0: hub_hub_status failed (err = -62)
hub 1-1.4:1.0: config failed, can't get hub status (err -62)
```

Strange: When I plug in an ordinary usb hub and into this hub I plug in the 5m cable it gets recognized and works properly.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this error?

Comment: I too have this going on. It must be a fairly generic error code. My case is I've got 3 usb web cams, two of the same model, one of the two produces this: "error -62"..